# Restore desktop icon locations after turning off the magnifier tool

Tags: windows-vista, desktop-icons, magnifier

I turned on the magnifier (Start > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Accesibility > Start Magnifier) and when I turned it off all of my desktop icons are mixed up, so I want to restore them.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would Right-Click\View\Auto-arrange and Align to Grid to be able to see all icons.

The order that you've set them ... is...err.. kind of impossible(Restart PC, Enter Safe Mode by pressing F8 then "restore last know good configuration" - highly possible that that it won't work as there wasn't any crash).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Unless you have a system crash, or a program that manages desktop icons, such as display fusion, then there is no way to 'restore' the configuration of your icons.